# Create a group chat using proactive message bot framework

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm working on a adaptive card and having a button on card which is a choice card as show card, on click of submit of that choice card i want to start a group chat with the select users.
I'm trying to do it using proactive message for group chat but didnt got any internet ref for the code using c#.
Can anyone suggest some ref for that.

```
   var conversationParameters = new ConversationParameters
                        {
                            IsGroup = true,
                             Members = new ChannelAccount[] { channelAccount1, channelAccount2, activity.Recipient, activity.From },
                            Activity = (Activity)message
                        };
                        var identity = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(MicrosoftAppId, MicrosoftAppPassword);
                        MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(activity.ServiceUrl);
                        var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl), identity);
                        ConversationResourceResponse CreateConversationResponse = await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParameters);
```

I'm getting bad request error

Comment: What channel is this for? creating a group conversation is going to be different for different channels (if it's even possible)